# Extract left and right from filename based on last delimiter using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I would like to extract left and right from filename based on last delimiter using shell script

```
Ex : filename = 'test_testone_test3_1234'

I'm expecting below values
     file = 'test_testone_test3'
     seq = '1234'
```

Is there a better approach to do it ?

Comment: Ordinarily, I'd suggest using [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) and/or [dirname](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname).  But those don't really seem to apply to your (unusual?) naming convention...

Comment: Please read the link Darkman cited (if you haven't already), "upvote" his answer (if you haven't already), review his examples ... and "Accept" if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to learn a little bit about [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```sh
$ filename="test_testone_test3_1234"
$ echo "${filename#*_}"
testone_test3_1234
$ echo "${filename##*_}"
1234
$ echo "${filename%_*}"
test_testone_test3
$ echo "${filename%%_*}"
test
$ echo "${filename#*_*_}"
test3_1234
$ echo "${filename%_*_*}"
test_testone
```

You can also use `cut`.`-d` is for field separator and `-f` for the fields.

```sh
$ filename="test_testone_test3_1234"
$ echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f1-3
test_testone_test3
$ echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f4
1234
$ echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f1-2
test_testone
$ echo "$filename" | cut -d_ -f3-
test3_1234
```

Comment: Thank you.I would like to extract on lefthand side before last two delimiters (test_testone)? Can you help me ?